# i want to run macro code in specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

i want to excute below code in specific sheet, without activating that sheet.

since **do while** references are in sheet1,code should work in sheet1.
when I working on sheet2 code dosenot work.

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use


Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
' connect to the Access database
'Dim sht As Worksheet


Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA SOURCE=D:\Trading\Option Analysis.accdb;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=FALSE;Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\Users\kishor\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System1.mdw;"
' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "CE", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
' all records in a table
r = 2 ' the start row in the worksheet



    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("Date") = Range("A" & r).Value
        .Fields("Time") = Range("B" & r).Value
        .Fields("LTP") = Range("C" & r).Value
        .Fields("Chg") = Range("D" & r).Value
        .Fields("OI") = Range("E" & r).Value
        .Fields("Volume") = Range("F" & r).Value
        .Fields("Strike_Price") = Range("G" & r).Value
        .Fields("Option_Type") = Range("H" & r).Value
        .Fields("OI_Change") = Range("I" & r).Value
        .Fields("IV") = Range("J" & r).Value
        .Fields("Expiry") = Range("K" & r).Value


        ' add more fields if necessary...
        .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
  
r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "PE", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
' all records in a table
r = 2 ' the start row in the worksheet



Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
With rs
.AddNew ' create a new record
' add values to each field in the record
.Fields("Date") = Range("O" & r).Value
.Fields("Time") = Range("P" & r).Value
.Fields("LTP") = Range("Q" & r).Value
.Fields("Chg") = Range("R" & r).Value
.Fields("OI") = Range("S" & r).Value
.Fields("Volume") = Range("T" & r).Value
.Fields("Strike_Price") = Range("U" & r).Value
.Fields("Option_Type") = Range("V" & r).Value
.Fields("OI_Change") = Range("W" & r).Value
.Fields("IV") = Range("X" & r).Value
.Fields("Expiry") = Range("Y" & r).Value

' add more fields if necessary...
.Update ' stores the new record
End With
r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "Spot", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
rs.AddNew ' create a new record
' add values to each field in the record
rs.Fields("Date") = Range("AB" & 2).Value
rs.Fields("Time") = Range("AC" & 2).Value
rs.Fields("Spot") = Range("AD" & 2).Value
rs.Fields("OI_SUM") = Range("AD" & 3).Value

rs.Update
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing



Call datatimer
End Sub
```

i want to excute below code in specific sheet, without activating that sheet.

since do while references are in sheet1,code should work in sheet1. when I working on sheet2 code dosenot work.
request for support from experts

Comment: Assuming `Sheet1` is the sheet codename, put `Sheet1.` before every `Range` call?

Comment: I believe you are correct @BigBen. It is defaulting to ActiveWorksheet when you leave out the sheet object. It also might be simpler to uncomment the Worksheet Dim and do this `sht = Sheets("Sheet2")`. Then all you have to add is `sht.`.

Comment: @ClintK - that's missing a `Set`, and it's still not fully qualified, since the workbook is not specified. And if `Sheet1` is the sheet codename, adding `Sheet1.` is better than using a worksheet variable.

Comment: It also might work to make sheet1 the active sheet at the top of the sub. `Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate`.

Comment: @BigBen - Thanks. I did forget the Set. If you intended to use the code in a different workbook then you could add it but it should not be necessary just for a separate sheet. How is Sheet1 better?

Comment: If the worksheet is in `ThisWorkbook`, then there's no question what `Sheet1` refers to, and it's less likely for the end user to change the worksheet code name. Note that `Sheets("Sheet2")` implicitly refers to the `ActiveWorkbook`, which may or may not be the correct one.

Comment: Thanks Bigben and ClintK, It is working now with Sheet1. before every Range